# GNU Octave: Increasing frequency tones of 5 sec with 0.1 sec in between

Tags: signals, octave, wav

I can produce a single tone with frequency and time duration of choice.

```
    >> fs = 44100;
    >> freq = 100;
    >> nsec = 5;
    >> nsample = fs*nsec;
    >> time = linspace(0,nsec,nsample);
    >> wave = sin(2*pi*freq*time);
    >> audiowrite('test-tone.wav',wave,fs);
```

I'd like to sequence together 100 single frequency tones increasing from 100 Hz to 10 kHz.
Each tone would last 5 sec and be separated by 0.1 sec.
Are there packages in Octave for this or is this likely to be a "for" statement?

I've followed the one reply to use a "for" loop. By searching and finding a bit of code (Kyung Seo Li) from the search, "how can i generate a sine wave with different frequencies using matlab?" I was able to create a sequence of frequencies as I asked. However, I still need to separate each frequency with a 0.1 second gap of zero amplitude. Should I add this to the "freqs" line or put it in the sine generation line? The code I'm currently working on is:

```
    fs = 8000;
    freqs = [100:50:5000];
    T = 1/fs; % sampling period
    dur = 5;
    y = [];
    for k = 1:size(freqs,2)
    x = sin(2*pi*freqs(k)*[0:T:dur-T]);
    y = horzcat(y,x);
    end
```

Lastly, any tips to Stackoverflow communication (other than those already listed on the website) are appreciated.

Comment: yes, do it in a for statement

Comment: Thank you Andy. I'm moving forward but still need help with the 0.1 sec gap in between each frequency. I've edited accordingly above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've increased the gap time and lowered the samples so you can clearly see it in the spectrogram. Btw, If you want to solve a problem, you should first try to make it as small as possible which makes it easier for you to debug the program (for example lower the steps from 100 to 2, decrease the sampling rate and so on). But here it is:

```
nsteps = 5;
fs = 44100;
f = linspace (100, 10e3, nsteps); # 100Hz to 10kHz
T = 5;  # length [s]
Tg = 0.5; # gap [s]

# preallocate memory with "0" for the gaps and because
# increasing a vector/matrix inside the loop is slow because
# of memory reallocation
y = zeros (1, numel(f) * (T + Tg) * fs);
for k=0:(numel(f) - 1)
  tstart_idx = round (k * (T + Tg) * fs);
  tend_idx = round ((k * (T + Tg) + T) * fs);
  r = (tstart_idx+1):(tend_idx+1);
  y(r) = sin (2 * pi * f(k+1) * (tstart_idx:tend_idx)/fs);
endfor

# only for visualization
pkg load signal
specgram (y, 512, fs)

# write wav
audiowrite('test-tone.wav', y, fs);
```

[image: specgram of generated signal]

Here you can see the generated signal from 10Hz to 10kHz in 5 steps with 0.5s gap.

Comment: Thanks a ton.How do I ask about the details of each line of code? Keep it on the thread or go outside?

Comment: You can ask in the comment and I can edit the code to include more comments. Any reason you haven't accepted the answer?

Comment: No reason. Just forgot. It is checked now. The #preallocate memory section is giving me trouble. Note that I am not a programmer or regular code writer. My sparse experience is mostly with SAS and R. What is the role of the zeros matrix? What does y(r) = perform?

Comment: You want to have gaps in the test signal where y is 0 so the idea is to preallocate the whole vector with zeros and only fill in the sin signal (leaving the gaps zero). If you instead increase a vector in a loop by adding elements to the end, Octave needs to reallocate (allocate new and copy the old content) memory many times which is slow. So preallocating the whole block and then adding the signal in the loop is also faster. `y(r) = ...` is a typical use of indexing. Try this in Octave which should make it clear:`a=zeros(1,5), b=[2 3], a(b)=[55 66]`

Comment: Totally clear. Light bulb went on. Thank you for your help and direction.